# libgio: get_connected_drives() returns an empty list

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, desktop-application, glib, disk-partitioning

I'm linking to libgio and using the VolumeMonitor class to retrieve the current mounted volumes. When i call get_connected_drives, it should return a list of drives (usb mass storage, cd drives) but it returns an empty list.

I made certain that i ran my program as root also.

Any ideas?

**Updated:** added example. Also i found with further investigation that it only returned an empty list when i ran it with root privileges. Is there something about linux that i don't understand?

```
VolumeMonitor monitor = VolumeMonitor.get ();

// Print a list of drives connected to the system:
List<Drive> drives = monitor.get_connected_drives ();
foreach (Drive drive in drives) {
    print_drive (drive, "Connected");
}
```